# Adding a dynamic field via javascript on RoR

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, erb

I would like to add dynamically fields to a form in a ERB file and I'm getting an issue that I don't know how to fix.

Basically, a user clicks a btn on a form and a new input text field is added via javascript. Right now, my code looks like this:

```
  <div class="form-group row">
      <button type="button" class="btn onclick="addManualInputFieldBtnPressed()">Add a manual input field</button>
  </div>

  <div id="manual_input_fields">
  </div>
```

and my javascript looks like this:

```
<script>
  var fields_index = -1;

  function addManualInputFieldBtnPressed() {
    fields_index += 1;
    
    $("#manual_input_fields").append('<div class="form-group row">\
                                        <%= form.label :new_text, class:"col-lg-3"  %>\
                                        <div class="col-lg-9">\
                                          <%= form.text_area :new_text, class:"form-control", size: "20x5" %>\
                                        </div>\
                                      </div>');
  }
</script>
```

If I add simple text it works, but as if I have the code above, I'm getting...

```
undefined local variable or method `form' for #<#<Class:0x00007fbf5c719940>:0x00007fbf5cc13108>
Did you mean?  for
               fork
```

I also tried with this code on my javascript part and I get a different error (related to rendering) but it didn't work either.

```
$("#manual_input_fields").append('<%= escape_javascript(<div class="form-group row">\
                                    <%= form.label :description, class:"col-lg-3 font-weight-bold text-dark col-form-label form-control-label text-2"  %>\
                                    <div class="col-lg-9">\
                                      <%= form.text_area :description, class:"form-control", size: "20x5" %>\
                                    </div>\
                                  </div>).html_safe %>');
```

Can someone point me to the right direction? I suppose that it must be something obvious but I'm a newbie on RoR.

Comment: You can append only html not ruby tags that's why you are getting this error. For this you have to call partial page and then render on button click.

Comment: That error message is very clear. You're referencing a local variable `form` that is not defined. If you want create inputs without a form use the bare bones input helpers instead of calling them on a form builder instance. https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html